# sides vs facets vs dimensions

Tags: vocabulary

> the [sides/facets/dimensions] of a problem.

Is there any difference between sides/facets/dimensions? Which one is more common and idiomatic?

Comment: Have you looked up the words in a dictionary? Dimensions are measurements, nothing to do with sides/facets.

Comment: A somewhat related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/334957/faces-and-sides-of-dice

Answer (score 1):

When speaking about literal geometric shapes, we normally use the word '*sides*'. With 3-dimensional shapes, we use the word '*faces*', although 'sides' may also be used.

Still speaking literally, '*facet*' is used to refer to the sides or faces of a cut gem, such as a diamond. It isn't normally interchangeable with 'sides' or 'faces' in this physical context. For example, a fixed object such as a building may have a 'left side' or a 'north face'. There are lots of reasons you wouldn't refer to any of the surfaces of a multi-faceted diamond in such a fixed way.

Your context is figurative though - and in this context, either could be used. Just remember that 'facets', like its literal use, suggests multiple aspects. Saying that a problem or issue is 'multi-faceted' suggests that it is *complex*. By contrast, it is common to say that there are "*two sides*" to something.

'Dimensions' does not have the same literal meaning as any of the above, but in a figurative sense it can mean '*properties*', which in turn can be used to refer to different aspects of something. You could use it in your example but it may not be as common. It better suggests that there are different depths to something rather than different ways of looking at it.

Comment: Thanks. So, in a figurative sense, can there be more than two sides to something? Could I talk about the many sides of something? For example: "Psychological counseling is one of the many sides of palliative care"